# How can I provide access only for some methods from service in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, solid, interface-segregation-principle

I have a two services an angular. The first one responsible for data manipulation and also has some methods which return data. The second one responsible for data rendering. RenderingService use two methods from DataManipulationService. How can I provide access only to these two methods with interface segregation principle without adding a new classes or service typization as an interface? For rest of methods I haven't to get access. Solution with private modificators isn't considering because this service uses in other parts of application.

I can provide some of my wrong attempts of solutions of this problem

I will be apreciate for any help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the native `private` and `public` keywords for all your service methods.

```
public myPublicMethod() { // do something public }

private myPrivateMethod() { // do something very secret }
```

Comment: Methods from this service used in other components so they have to be a public. I have a hint that the solution in interface segregation principle. I tried to solve it with additional class and the casting service type as interface but it's unfortunetely anti pattern.

Comment: @VovaAleshchenko In that case, there isn't a clean way to restrict a method to be accessible for some consumers, but not for others. You'll have to redesign _something_ here. I'd suggest re-writing your question to describe what exactly you're trying to accomplish, so that people can help you re-thinking your pattern.